# How Can I pass GET and POST parameters using Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client

Tags: php, symfony

Do You know how I can pass GET and POST parameters using Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client for testing purposes ? I have been tried:

```
$crawler = $client->request( 'POST', '/metrics/v1/submit?token=esyurtgf634tfr7w4g67awt3b57ta683fwr5t84w:notice:timestamp:hashCode', array(
            'metrics' =>
                array( ... )));
```

but unfortunately i can't access neither GET parameters nor POST parameters, official documentation don't help in any way because, i didn't found any example similar to mine. I would be thankful for any help.